# MemoryCache doesn't store IReadOnlyList

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.6, memorycache

I tired setting a populated IReadOnlyList to cache but it was always null:

```
CacheItemPolicy cip = new CacheItemPolicy(); // no expiration
IReadOnlyList<T> dataList = [populate var]

if (dataList != null)
{
   MemoryCache.Default.Set(_cacheKey, dataList, cip);
}
```

Nothing is set in Cache. But if I change it to:

```
List<T> list = null;
CacheItemPolicy cip = new CacheItemPolicy(); // no expiration
IReadOnlyList<T> dataList = [populate var]

if (dataList != null)
{
   list = dataList.ToList();       
   MemoryCache.Default.Set(_cacheKey, list, cip);
}
```

it works. Does MemoryCache not support interfaces or the IReadOnlyList object?

Comment: How do you populate the `dataList` list?

Comment: It is actually passed in a function, to keep the example simple I removed the function wrapping the call.

Comment: What is the type of the object that is returned from the function? (Not the function return type, but the actual type of the returned value in your particular case). I don't think the variable type matters, but maybe the type of the object matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MemoryCache is caching the reference to the list in the first example and a copy of the list in the second example.

It must be your code is reusing the list passed in as dataList and so you require a copy to be cached.  Calling ToList() makes a copy.